# Fail to insert start date and end date in database using cakephp

Tags: mysql, date, cakephp

I want to insert value for start date and end date in database using cakephp. If I uncomment `$data = $controller->request>data;` then I get error like this : Warning (2): Cannot use a scalar value as an array [APP\Model\MattersCase.php, line 40] but when I comment `$data = $controller->request>data;` my data get inserted but value for start date and end date is `0000-00-00`.

**cases.ctp**

```
    <tr>
<td valign=top class="form_label_width">Start Date:</td>
                        `enter code here`<td><?php echo $this->element("date", array('name' => 'data[MattersCase][start_date]', 'id' => 'start_date', 'value' => cleanDate($global_date_format, strtotime($start_date)), 'required' => false)); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign=top>End Date:</td>
                        <td><?php echo $this->element("date", array('name' => 'data[MattersCase][end_date]', 'id' => 'end_date', 'value' => cleanDate($global_date_format, strtotime($end_date)), 'required' => false)); ?>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

**MattersCase.php**

```
public function execute(&$controller, $task, $case_id)
    {          

       $data = $controller->request>data;
       $types = $controller->MattersCategory->getCategoryListNew12(0, true);
       $controller->set("types", $controller->sanitizeHTML($types));

       $providertypes = $controller->MattersUserAccount->getProviderTypes(0, true);
       $controller->set("providertypes", $controller->sanitizeHTML($providertypes));

        switch($task)
        {
            case "addnew":
            {       
                if (!empty($controller->request->data))
                {
                    $this->create();                                                
                    echo "clean out--".$data['MattersCase']['start_date'] = cleanDate("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(str_replace("-", "/", $controller->request->data['MattersCase']['start_date'])));
                    //echo "clean--".$data['MattersCase']['start_date'] = cleanDate("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(str_replace("-", "/", $controller->request->data['MattersCase']['start_date'])));

                    if($this->save($data))
                    //if ($controller->MattersCase->save($controller->request->data))
                    {
                        echo "<pre>";
                        print_r($controller->request->data);
                        $controller->Session->setFlash(__('Data added.', true));
                            //$controller->redirect(array('action' => $action));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $controller->Session->setFlash('Sorry, data can\'t be saved.', 'default', array('class' => 'error'));
                    }
                    if ($controller->MattersCase->save($controller->request->data))
                    {

                        $controller->Session->setFlash(__('Data added.', true));
                        //$controller->redirect(array('action' => 'cases'));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $controller->Session->setFlash('Sorry, data can\'t be saved.', 'default', array('class' => 'error'));
                    }
                }

            } break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you missing a dash (minus sign: `-`) after the word "request"? So that the line of code is `$data = $controller->request->data`

Comment: Yes, Have corrected the mistake. But still value of date is not getting inserted in database. Printed output like this start date value is 2014-10-15 00:00:00
Array([data1] => Array([MattersCase] => Array(user_id] => Array([0] =>[1] =>)))[MattersCase] => Array(
            [category_id] => 1
            [case_name] => Case 1
            [case_number] => Case N.
            [description] => Description
            [client_name] => Client Name
            [start_date] => 10/15/2014
            [end_date] => 10/28/2014
            [referred_by] => test
            [status] => Open))